# Convert dictionary entries to a single string formatted with spaces between values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with name followed by 3 different numbers. I need a function to convert the dictionary entries to a single string or a to a list then to a single string. And then I need to format the string to be instead of (john [100, 1550.0, 46.5]) to be (John   100   1550.0    46.5). (so with multiple spaces and no commas or square brackets).

I've tried creating empty lists to help but I think I'm pretty far off:

outlist = [quantity, price, discount]

My dictionary: orders[name] = outlist

```
def make_string_from_list():
        temp = []
        orderslist = []
        for key, value in orders.items():
            temp = [key,value]
            orderslist.append(temp)
        str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in orderslist)
        print(str1)
```

so typing in name and quantity will return name, quantity, price of order, and the discount

Comment: Pleas share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you describe a bit more precisely the structure of your input dictionary, or at least an example of it?

Comment: you can try either `"{foo: [bar, baz]}".replace(',', ' ')` or use `re.sub()` to do replacements after you stringify your dict or lists with `str()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input dict looks like:

```py
input_dict = {
    'name': [value1, value2, value3],
    ....
}
```

I would use a function such as this one:

```py
def format_dict(input_dict):
    for name, values in input_dict.items():
        print('{name} {values}'.format(
            name=name,
            values=' '.join([str(v) for v in values])
        ))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. Thank you!!